# rhc setup command raises Gem::LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.I followed the insructions for setting up rhc client tools..Finally I used rhc setup command to setup my account.But it showed me an error for which i could not find an answer in the internet after searching for a long time.So please give me a solution.
Error details:

arun@arun-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~$ rhc setup
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:774:in `block in activate_dependencies': can't satisfy 'highline (~> 1.6.11)', already activated 'highline-1.7.1' (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in`each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in`activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:22:in`'

Answer (score 1):

On windows 7, it works with the following commands.

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem install rhc
```

https://github.com/openshift/rhc/issues/678